# Which MIME data type for Android Excel CSV?

Tags: android, excel, csv

I tried "text/csv" and even "application/vnd.ms-excel", but Excel won't show in the list of choices.  Plenty of other apps do.

```
void shareCsv(Uri uri, Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/csv");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

For me, these mime types worked:

- **XLS** => `application/vnd.ms-excel`
- **XLSX** => `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`
- **CSV** => `text/comma-separated-values`

Answer (score 5):

It should be `application/vnd.ms-excel` ([source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsofficedeveloper/2008/05/08/office-2007-file-format-mime-types-for-http-content-streaming-2/))

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
void shareCsv(Uri uri, Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("application/excel") //replace "text/csv" with application/excel
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Here's a **[link](https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list/)** to the `.xls` mime-types you can use. If one type isn't working for you, try another.

List of choices for Excel:

- `application/excel`
- `application/vnd.ms-excel`
- `application/x-excel`
- `application/x-msexcel`