# Xamarin.Forms - How to define scoped storage for android and how can I implement it to downlaod files in Downloads directory?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my app I have given facility to download reports in PDF formats. Everything was good until I was testing my app on Android 10 and below. Recently I updated a device to Android 11 and now I am not able to download any file in shared storage. I am getting `Access Denied` error while downloading file.

I have given permission to read and write external storage

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and my download path is

```
Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath;
```

I have also set `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

My code to download file looks like this

```
public async void DownloadSupplierSample(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string basepath;
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
                basepath = DependencyService.Get<IDownloadPath>().GetDownloadsPath();
            else
                basepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "..", "Library");

            PermissionStatus readstatus = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
            PermissionStatus writestatus = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();

            if (readstatus == PermissionStatus.Granted && writestatus == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                DownloadSupplier(basepath);
            }
            else
            {
                var read = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
                var write = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();

                if (read == PermissionStatus.Granted && write == PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    DownloadSupplier(basepath);
                }
            }
            await DisplayAlert("", "Sample is downaloaded at Downloads directory","Ok");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    async void DownloadSupplier(string basepath)
    {
        using (var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("SupplierMaster.xlsx"))
        {
            string filename = $"SupplierMaster_{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")}.xlsx";
            string filepath = Path.Combine(basepath, filename);

            byte[] bytes = Utils.Common.StreamToBytes(stream);
            File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, bytes);
            //using (Stream filestream = File.Create(filepath))
            //{
            //    //stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            //    stream.CopyTo(filestream);
            //}
        }
    }
```

I have tried setting flag from device as well from this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-compatibility/test-debug#:%7E:text=Toggle%20changes%20using%20the%20developer%20options,-Use%20the%20developer&text=enabled%2C%20enable%20them.-,Open%20your%20device%27s%20Settings%20app%20and%20navigate%20to%20System%20%3E%20Advanced,off%20and%20tap%20the%20switch.)

How can I define scoped storage for my app ?

Any update how can I download PDF file in my downloads directory ?

Thank you.

Comment: On an Android 11 device you should be able to create a file in the Download directory on external storage like you could on other Android versions. You have no download problem but just a file creation problem in Download directory that i do not understand. You added code to ask the user to confirm write permissions at runtime? (Not that it is needed on an Android 11 device..)

Comment: `and my download path is` That is your code to get a path. Which path do you get? Please tell value. Full path please.

Comment: here is the path I get for Download directory `/storage/emulated/0/Download/SupplierMaster_20210310141155.xlsx`. And If I am able to download file even In Android 11, then why I am getting Access Denied error ? And this works on Android 10 or below

Comment: Access Denied to what? You are saying `getting Access Denied error while downloading file` but i dont think so. Its while trying to create a file.

Comment: yeah, my mistake, you are correct. the error comes when I try to create file

Comment: what should I do to solve this error ?

Comment: It's all in my first comment. And the question in it you still did not answer.

Comment: yes I ask for write permission at runtime. The code I have written for read and write in above code. If user doesn't have, I call `var read = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
                var write = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();` to request the same. Hopefully this code is correct.

Comment: Sorry, i do not understand why you cant create a file in Download directory. I give up. What kind of device?

Comment: I have Samsung M31 Having Android 11 OS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue a couple of months ago.

**I found this on developer.android page:**
[image]
(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory())

The first alternative (getExternalFilesDir) won't work as you want, files won't appear in the download directory, this location is internal to the app.

The second alternative is for media files.

I ended up using the third alternative. I created a service class in Android project, something like this:

```
public class FilesManager : IFilesManager
{
    private const int CREATE_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 123;
    private static Context _context;
    
    public static void Init(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task SaveFile(string fileName, byte[] content)
    { 
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCreateDocument);
        intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
        intent.SetType(your_file_mimeType);
        intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraTitle, fileName);

        var activity = (MainActivity)_context;
        var listener = new ActivityResultListener(activity);
        activity.StartActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

        var result = await listener.Task;

        if (result == null)
        {
            // Cancelled by user
            return;
        }

        using (Stream os = _context.ContentResolver.OpenOutputStream(result.Data))
        {
            os?.Write(content);
            os?.Close();
        }
    }

    private class ActivityResultListener
    {
        private readonly TaskCompletionSource<Intent> Complete = new TaskCompletionSource<Intent>();
        public Task<Intent> Task { get { return this.Complete.Task; } }

        public ActivityResultListener(MainActivity activity)
        {
            // subscribe to activity results
            activity.ActivityResult += OnActivityResult;
        }

        private void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if(requestCode != CREATE_FILE_REQUEST_CODE)
            {
                return;
            }

            // unsubscribe from activity results
            var activity = (MainActivity)_context;
            activity.ActivityResult -= OnActivityResult;

            // process result
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                Complete.TrySetResult(data);
            }
            else
            {
                Complete.TrySetResult(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In MainActivity.cs add:

```
public event Action<int, Result, Intent> ActivityResult;

protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    ActivityResult?.Invoke(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
}
```

You can call Init method after Forms.Init:

```
FilesManager.Init(this);
```

**Note:** This method requires user interaction. The user will be prompted to choose the location where to save the file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am getting error at `activity.ActivityResult`. `ActivityResult` not found. what should I add in MainActivity ?

Comment: Thanks for your editing the answer. Do I need to call `Init` before calling `SaveFile` ? because I am getting null in `_context`.

Comment: Thank you so much @alexgavru for your kind help. It is working now.

Comment: sorry to disturb you again. file is downloaded fine but it is not uploaded now. it was working file before. I am using `xamarin.essentials` to pick file. I want to upload same file again from download/documents folder. but I get path of Application folder `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com..../cache/2203693cc04e0be7f4f024d5f9499e13/4d965438354c46cd8a684c0df3b40d9f/SupplierMaster_20210319160515.xlsx.xls` when I choose file from downloads folder. The file is actually downloaded on that path as well. what should be gone wrong ?

Comment: I am using `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` mime type. Also I tried for [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46651821/5509235) as well

Comment: @Monica sorry, for the late response, I missed the notification. I'm not sure what happens there, why is there .xlsx.xls file extension? Is that ok?

Comment: yes actually I am also confused because of that. Again, it is happening only in Android 11 not in below OS. For below versions, it is getting correct path of downloads folder. At the time of downloading I have only given .xlsx extension to file name.

Comment: I think it's a file picker problem if the file is downloaded correctly and the name and extension look good.

Comment: okay, I will try different file picker to upload file and let you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I define scoped storage for my app ?Any update how can I download PDF file in my downloads directory ?

Android 10 introduced a new storage paradigm for apps called scoped storage which changes the way apps store and access files on a device's external storage. If you target Android 10 (API level 29) or higher, set the value of requestLegacyExternalStorage to true in your app's manifest file.

```xml
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:label="FormsSample.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme"></application>
```

Then request runtime write and read EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission before access download folder.

```cs
public void requestpermission()
{
    if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted)
    {
        ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage }, 1);
    }


    if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted)
    {
        ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage }, 1);
    }
}
```

Create interface IAccessFileService in Xamarin.Forms shared code.

```cs
public interface IAccessFileService
{
    void CreateFile(string FileName);
}
```

Implementing IAccessFileService interface on Android platform.You could use `File.Exists(xx)` to check if the folder exists, and use `Directory.CreateDirectory(xx)` to create the folder if not.

```cs
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(AccessFileImplement))]
namespace FormsSample.Droid
{
    public class AccessFileImplement : IAccessFileService
    {
        public void CreateFile(string FileName)
        {
            string text = "hello world";
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
            string rootPath = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
            var filePathDir = Path.Combine(rootPath, "folder");
            if (!File.Exists(filePathDir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(filePathDir);
            }
            string filePath = Path.Combine(filePathDir, FileName);
            File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, data);
        }

        
    }
}
```

So using [dependencyservice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to call android CreateFile method.

```cs
private void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DependencyService.Get<IAccessFileService>().CreateFile("test.txt");
}
```

Comment: okay, that means I have to implement File creation logic seperate on Android and iOS. I will surely give it a try. thank you for your answer

Comment: @Monica If my reply help you, please remember to remember to mark my reply as answer.

Comment: Yes sure, I have written your code but not able to test it. Becuase from last 2 hours I am not able to run my app on android project. `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/Users/apple/Library/Android/sdk'.`. once I solve this, i will test and mark your answer as accepted

Comment: I am getting this error again. It was working yesterday. But same access denied issue came again.

Comment: @Monica You use Visual studio for mac? If yes, please manually copy the Android SDK files from the default path to the hardcoded path in the error message, more detailed info, please take a look:[Xamarin.Forms would not compile Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66564661/xamarin-forms-would-not-compile-android-project)

Comment: I solved that error related to android sdk not loading.

Comment: @Monica If my reply help you, please remember to mark my reply as answer, it may be helpful to others, thanks.